# AJAX request connected with PHP by json - no action

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm having a problem with connection AJAX with PHP. The main goal is to send an request to PHP where we can execute method to delete an image. Every thing sounds nice and simple but the whole connection is not working properly - basicly it's not working at all.

The is the simpliest example about what I would like to achive.

jQuery code:

```
$("span.deleteTmp").live("click", function() {
    obj_a = $(this);
    if (confirm("Want to delete the file?")) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "index.php?mode=functions&method=deleteFile",
            data: {
                pict_name: obj_a.attr("id")
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data.msg);
                if (data.success == true) {
                    obj_a.parents("li").remove();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});​
```

PHP example code:

```
/* invoking methods */
if(isset($_GET['method'])) {
   $method = $_GET['method'];
   call_user_func($method);
}

/* methods */
function deleteFile() {
   $result = array('success'=>true, 'msg' => "OK");
   echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Moreover when I type in browser index.php?mode=functions&method=deleteFile I get correct response such as: `{"success":true,"msg":"OK"}`

What am I doing wrong in this case?

Comment: Could you post your HTML source?

Comment: Does it work with an absolute URL? It would be a good idea to use debugging tools in chrome/firefox and see if you find the problem there.  For chrome, open the developer tools -> Network -> XHR.  Then run your ajax function

Comment: I've changed the data type to post and I receive request on the server side using $_POST['pict_name']. I think it's the easiest way in this case. Moveover Istill don't now what was wrong with the json data type to send... but when I figured it out I will let u know ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using JQuery I am going to write this in JQuery.

First off `live` is either deprecated or being deprecated.

Another tip is don't use GET to modify and delete stuff from your server since some one could easily abuse that. Also you are allowing the GET to dictate, without any real validation, what function should be run like: `index.php?mode=functions&method=deleteFile`. Someone could easily change that to define a function you DON'T want running directly from the website.

So the first thing I would do is change live to on() like:

```
$(".deleteTmp").on('click', function(e){
    if(confirm('delete?'){
        $.get('index.php', {mode: 'functions', method: 'deleteFile', pict_name: $(this).attr('id')}, function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }, 'json');
    }
});
```

Something like that should give you the right result. Open up your console with f12 and see what it gives you back and of course make sure the actual event is running when you click the element, I know it sounds stupid but I have made the mistake of sitting there for hours thinking why AJAX wouldn't run only to find it wasn't even firing the `click` event.

### Edit

however I do see your actual problem. You are defining two GETs for JQuery, first in the url:

```
index.php?mode=functions&method=deleteFile",
```

Then in the data:

```
pict_name: obj_a.attr("id")
```

If I remember correctly JQuery in this context will actually fire a AJAX call to:

```
index.php?pict_name=whatever
```

So try my code above.

Comment: obviously I did similar to yours solution. I used POST to send data rather than json. In my case, I only use json to receive response from server side. It's working perfectly. But as I've mention above - I'll let u know if I figure out the right way to implement my first thought.

Comment: @lokatek When were you using JSON? I see thne return being JSON but I don't see you sending JSON

Answer (score 0):

If you get the expected reply when accessing the query URL directly, then you should check that the previous steps are working. Try to use Firebug, or "inspect element" or so (depending on the browser you are using), then go to the "Network" tab to inspect if your request is being sent and check that the values of the variables are correct. If that's not the case, then check that there isn't a more obvious error like a typo or an incorrect name in the class name for the element you are trying to get the "click" event on.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set up headers before output JSON results, for example like this:

```
function deleteFile() {
   $result = array('success'=>true, 'msg' => "OK");
   header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate'); // prevent the browser from caching the response
   header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // prevent the browser from caching the response
   header('Content-type: application/json'); // sets the correct MIME type for JSON
   echo json_encode($result);
}
```